# Query Disconnected RecordSet

Tags: vbscript, ado, recordset

Background:  a LOB app we use has the ability to use macros written in VBScript, but no access to WScript, etc., as far as I know.

I have successfully received user input, passed it to a stored procedure on a SQL Server, and returned a recordset to the VBScript macro in the application.

What I want to do now, is write a function or loop or something, that for as long as there is a record left in the recordset, accept additional user input, and check this against the returned recordset.

The recordset returned from SQL Server contains two columns:  PART_ID and PART_QTY.  For as many number of entries there are, I want to accept additional user input, lets say PART_ID_INPUT and PART_QTY_INPUT, and validate it against the in-memory recordset.

My biggest problem is working with the disconnected recordset.

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675841). You can use the [`Filter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676691) and [`RecordCount`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676701) properties to determine if the recordset contains matching records:

```
part_id_input = InputBox("Enter part ID:")

If part_id_input <> "" Then
  rs.Filter = "PART_ID = '" & part_id_input & "'"
  If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then WScript.Echo "Found matching record."
End If
```

The filter is cleared by setting it to an empty string:

```
rs.Filter = ""
```

The current record can be removed from the recordset using the [`Delete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675261) method:

```
rs.Delete
```

Navigate through records via [`MoveFirst`/`MoveLast`/`MoveNext`/`MovePrevious`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677527).